# Inserting data into PostgreSQL table from MATLAB with JDBC throws BatchUpdateException

Tags: sql, matlab, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to write to a PostgreSQL database table from MATLAB. I have got the connection working using JDBC and created the table, but I am getting a BatchUpdateException when I try to insert a record.

The MATLAB query to insert the data is:

```
user_table = 'rm_user';
colNames = {user_id};
data = {longRecords(iterator)};
fastinsert(conn, user_table, colNames, data);
```

The exception says:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO rm_user (user_id) VALUES ( '4') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

But I don't know how to call `getNextException` from MATLAB.

Any ideas what's causing the problem or how I can find out more about the exception?

**EDIT**

Turns out I was looking at documentation for a newer version of MATLAB than mine. I have changed from `fastinsert` to `insert` and it is now working. However, I'm still interested in knowing if there is a way I could use `getNextException` from MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
try
   user_table = 'rm_user';
   colNames = {user_id};
   data = {longRecords(iterator)};
   fastinsert(conn, user_table, colNames, data);
catch err
   err.getNextException ()
end
```

Alternatively, just look at the caught error, it should contain the same information.

Also, Matlab has a function [lasterr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lasterr.html) which will give you the last error without a catch statement. The function is deprecated, but you can find the documentation for replacements at the link provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't have MATLAB anymore (I had a student licence when I was doing my masters degree), so I can't test your suggestion.